# How to find the coordinates of moving objects to draw rectangle

Tags: opencv

Does anyone know how to locate the coordinates of the moving object? I have found some examples online about tracking the objects by using optical flow, but I only got some tracked points on the moving objects. May I just draw rectangle around the each moving object instead? Is there a way to get the coordinates of each moving object? Appreciate any help in advance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fit a rectangle to the points you get with optical flow and you can consider the centre of the  fitted rectangle as a fair estimate of 2D trajectory of the whole moving body..

Answer (score 1):

u can use the Moments operator

first calculate the contour size....
and just add this code block

```
Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
           area = moment.m00;//m00 gives the area
                       x = moment.m10/area;//gives the x coordinate
                    y = moment.m01/area;  //gives y coordiante
```

where the contours is the output of the findcontours(),

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty hard to tell the coordinates of an object only from a couple of points on it. You can use moments ([here is a tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html)) tu get a quite stable point describing where is Your object.

<del>You may also do some additional work, like segmentation using tracked points to get the contour of tracked object, which should make it even easier to find its mass centre.</del> Went overboard with ths.

There is also a tracking method called [`CAMSHIFT`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#camshift) which returns a rectangle bounding the tracked object.

If You know precisely what are You tracking, and can make sure that some known points on tracked object are tracked, and You are able to recognise them, than You can use POSIT to determine the object's 3D coordinates and orientation. Take a glance at [ArUco](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/) to get the idea about what I'm talking about.

To get the 3D position from previous methods, You can use stereo vision, and use centre of mass from both cameras to compute the coordinates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am confused about the relation between segmentation and tracking. I tried to use background subtraction to get the contour of moving objects, but how can I track them? Do I still need to use optical flow,but how?

Comment: I just threw the segmentation as a free suggestion. Should have dig some more to see how it is actually used. Anyway, You can draw a rectangle around them, You may use the centre of mass, or anything else, as long as You are consistent with it, so every object is located the same way. As for precise location, You might want to use [`calcPyrOpticalFlowLK`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=pyrlk#calcopticalflowpyrlk), as it tracks previously set features on the scene, instead just showing where is any movement.